# cannot edit DataGrid cells if ItemsSource is bound to linq expression

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I am getting exception "'EditItem' is not allowed for this view" when I try to edit an item in my grid view. This is because I bind the data grid to a LINQ query. My question is how to filter my original collection of items? Do I have to create another ObservableCollection (or whatever else implements IList) and copy my filtered items there?

EDIT: I know that duplicating data in to an ObservableCollection works. My question is: given the original collection, is there a memory efficient (constant memory complexity) way to filter and/or order the collection and make it editable inside the grid view?

`private readonly ObservableCollection tasks = new ObservableCollection();

        public IEnumerable OrderedTasks
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tasks.Where(t => !t.Complete);
            }
        }`


    `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderedTasks}" />`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try it and find out than post a question to SO?

Comment: I do not understand. try what?

Comment: Try doing what you suggested in your question.

Comment: Have you looked at [How to: Filter Data in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx)?